# PHPUnit code coverage for "require_once" statements

Tags: php, phpunit, code-coverage, xdebug

Can I exclude "require_once" statements from code coverage? The lines with "require_once" are reported as not covered but it is not possible if other lines in the script are covered:

[image]

PHP 7.0.11, PHPUnit 5.5.7 & XDebug 2.4.0 are used for code coverage.

Answer (score 4):

In the [PHPUnit documentation](https://phpunit.de/manual/current/en/code-coverage-analysis.html) there is mentioning of excluding code blocks from coverage using `@codeCoverageIgnoreStart` / `@codeCoverageIgnoreEnd` / `@codeCoverageIgnore` comments.

So you can try something like:

```
// @codeCoverageIgnoreStart
require_once __DIR__ . '/Data/TData.php';
require_once __DIR__ . '/Data/Path.php';
// @codeCoverageIgnoreEnd
```

or

```
require_once __DIR__ . '/Data/TData.php'; // @codeCoverageIgnore
require_once __DIR__ . '/Data/Path.php'; // @codeCoverageIgnore
```

Answer (score 3):

You have [`forceCoversAnnotation`](https://phpunit.de/manual/current/en/appendixes.configuration.html) enabled.

> `forceCoversAnnotation`
>
> Code Coverage will only be recorded for tests that use the `@covers` annotation documented in [the section called "`@covers`"](https://phpunit.de/manual/current/en/appendixes.annotations.html#appendixes.annotations.covers).
>
> — [Appendix C. The XML Configuration File](https://phpunit.de/manual/current/en/appendixes.configuration.html)

Disabling `forceCoversAnnotation` will produce coverage of the `require_once` calls.

For example, you can disable `forceCoversAnnotation` in the `phpunit.xml` configuration file:

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="UTF-8"?>
<phpunit forceCoversAnnotation="false">
...
```

If you want to use `@covers` annotations then you will either need to disable [`checkForUnintentionallyCoveredCode`](https://phpunit.de/manual/current/en/risky-tests.html#risky-tests.unintentionally-covered-code) or wrap the `require_once` calls in `@codeCoverageIgnore*` annotations.

Either

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="UTF-8"?>
<phpunit forceCoversAnnotation="true"
         checkForUnintentionallyCoveredCode="false">
...
```

Or

```
// @codeCoverageIgnoreStart
require_once __DIR__ . '/Data/TData.php';
require_once __DIR__ . '/Data/Path.php';
// @codeCoverageIgnoreEnd
```

The reason, is that using `forceCoversAnnotation` means you want to specify everything that is covered explicitly. You do this by using the `@covers` annotations. The `@uses` annotation let's you specify code that is intentionally covered by a test. But `@uses` can't be used to specify code that causes side-effects e.g. `require_once` statements. This is where `@codeCoverageIgnoreStart` and `@codeCoverageIgnoreEnd` comes in, it allows you to explicitly specify code that coverage should ignore.

Most of these annotations are about strictness of code coverage.